# Closure Issue in React Custom Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures

I wonder what's going on here. I finally **moved the variable `curPage` to the global scope** in my custom hook as the closure doesn't work for some weird reason. So well... the problem is solved but it doesn't look elegant and I'm really concerned why?

This hook is responsible for pagination but it doesn't really matter what it does. The variable `let curPage = 1;` that holds the value matters as it's the value that increments everytime the function `getItems` runs.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

// let curPage = 1; I MOVED IT HERE AND WORKS BUT ... well

const usePagination = items => {
  const [itemsToRender, setItemsToRender] = useState(items.slice(0, 4));

  let curPage = 1;
  let maximumItems = 4;
  let totalPages = Math.ceil(items.length / maximumItems);

  //get 4 items per each page;
  const getItems = () => {
    curPage += 1;

    const min = (curPage - 1) * maximumItems;
    const max = curPage * maximumItems;

    setItemsToRender(state => state.concat(items.slice(min, max)));
  };

  return { getItems, itemsToRender, curPage, totalPages };
};

export default usePagination;
```

The hook is called in some React component function and I immediately destructure returned object.

```
const { getItems, itemsToRender } = usePagination(articles);
```

**TO SUM UP THE PROBLEM**: everytime the function `getItems` is called, the variable `curPage` is always 1 by default. So it will always return 2  when `curPage += 1;` so the logic fails as within every click for example it should grow - 1,2,3,4,5 etc.

The hook is called once and the returned function `getItems` is called multiple times but the variable `curPage` is enclosed within custom hook function body so should mutate everytime the function runs.

I don't understand what's going on. I will appreciate your suggestions. Thanks in advance! Maciej

Comment: Either use state or ref. No other way to save variables between rerenders

Comment: `The hook is called once` - no, the hooks is called every time a state changes or the parent rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

It is React. It rerenders stuff. That means your component (that is function) gets called again and again and again on each rerender when state updates.

1. You define `curPage = 1`
2. then you increment it `curPage += 1`
3. then you update state via `setItemsToRender`
4. then your component rerenders (executes again)
5. and again `curPage = 1`

A solution for this is to use `useRef`. It keeps the changed value between renders (thanks to closures)

```
const curPage = useRef(1)

curPage.current += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, it's a closure issue, it's very commonly seen in React hooks. The solution is to "break" the closure and make the function realize the change of `curPage`.

1. As Oktay Yuzcan pointed out, use `useRef()`, it's not a part of the closure so it can help the function know what happens outside of the closure.

```
let curPage = useRef(1);

const getItems = () => {
  curPage.current++;
}
```

2. Use `useCallback()` to update the function when the value of `curPage` changes.

```
let curPage = 1;

const getItems = useCallback(() => {
  curPage++;
}, [curPage]);
```

For your situation solution 1 is better since solution 2 recreates the function every time the `curPage` changes whereas solution 1 only needs to maintain a simple ref.

Another approach to avoid closure is moving the variable to the inside function, so it's not a part of the closure but a part of the function itself. Yet that's not fitting your situation here.